# Can I use javax.script in Android development and if yes how?

Tags: javascript, android, function, eval

I'm having a bit of trouble with including javax.script.*; in an Android project.
 I need it so I can use the "eval" function in JavaScript, in order to parse arithmetic functions efficiently, without building a parser myself (I have utterly no experience in that and not a lot of time on my hands).

Is there any chance to use JavaScript or the "eval" function or something similar in my Android app?

Thanks for any info you can give me

Comment: To my knowledge, JavaScript is only packaged with the JDK from Sun. You could possibly make Rhino work, though the effort involved seems pretty large compared with just writing a simple expression parser.

Comment: I'll probably end up writing the parser in the end...Apparently there's no straight forward way of using that eval function (so far to my knowledge...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the JS code with [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/). It should do what you need but is simpler than the entire Javascript interpreter.