# Why have some java libraries been kept out of android sdk?

Tags: java, android

All java libraries are not present within android e.g. `javax.script, java.awt.*` etc. It makes it very difficult to use a lot of useful libraries written in java (e.g. libraries for java script evaluation, image processing, etc.).

I am just curious, would anyone have an idea as to why android team has decided to keep these out of android sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-vs-android-apis/504) might provide some basic explanation:

> Google’s mobile phone platform, Android, supports a relatively large
>   subset of the Java Standard Edition 5.0 library. Some things were left
>   out because they simply didn’t make sense (like printing), and others
>   because better APIs are available that are specific to Android (like
>   user interfaces).

I think that other reasons might include the fact that the mobile platform does not have the computational resources that other devices such as laptops and desktops might have (even though this seems to be changing with the introduction of high end mobile phones).

Edit: I think that the concept of 'usefulness' varies, so what yourself find useful might not be so for other people. If you want specific reasons why this specific package was left out, it is of my opinion that you are asking it in the wrong place. With regards to this specific package, the `javax.script`, you might want to consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967824/can-i-use-javax-script-in-android-development-and-if-yes-how) previous SO post which proposes an alternative.

Comment: yes ok some libraries you mensioned above just dont make sense so its logical to exclude these but why not include usefull ones like javax.script

Comment: hmmm... i guess, not bloating the sdk would also be an incentive to keep these out.

Comment: I have edited my response, hopefully it will answer some of your queries.

Comment: from what i understand, different libraries would have different reasons for why they didn't get included... hmmm..